# iOS Audio Playback Over Phone Call

Tags: ios, audio, microphone, phone-call

I've found a few related questions for Android but nothing for iOS.

Is there any possible way to override the phone's microphone once a phone call has been received and playback an audio file over the phone call? If it's not possible to override the microphone, is there a way to mix in an audio file along with the microphone?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can do what you're wanting. From Apple's [Audio Session Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/audio/conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/ConfiguringanAudioSession/ConfiguringanAudioSession.html):

> The system follows the inviolable rule that “the phone always wins.” No app, no matter how vehemently it demands priority, can trump the phone. When a call arrives, the user gets notified and your app is interrupted—no matter what audio operation you have in progress and no matter what category you have set.

Which, if you think about it, makes sense: A user is unlikely to want unexpected audio to interrupt or overlay a phone conversation.